# minecraft-pi is not working

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen, screen, minecraft

I use VNC viewer to connect my Pi 3, laptop and Kuman 7" touchscreen, because I cannot get access to a keyboard or mouse. When I open minecraft-pi it shows just a black screen on my laptop, but it loads on my pi screen, and I can click in and play (only the mouse works, the keyboard doesn't). How do I make my laptop's keyboard work with minecraft-pi if it works usually in other circumstances such as editing code, and how can I make it show up on my laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your using RealVNC on the Pi. You need to turn on the 'experimental direct capture mode'.

> To turn this feature on, open the VNC Server dialog, navigate to Menu
>   - Options - Troubleshooting, and select 'Enable experimental direct capture mode'

https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/raspberry-pi.html

Comment: What do you mean by 'Server Dialog'? When I open VNC, I only get 'File', 'View' and 'Help' on the top bar and none of them contain 'Menu'.

Comment: On the Pi you should have a VNC icon on the task bar, right click should give a menu.